# Check for common IDs with different statuses in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got one table, let's call it Tab1, that looks like this:
[Tab1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtJzr.png)

I want to know which "order" and "product", together, have status "sent" without having status "packed" before, I'm not interested in status "ready" at all.

Result in this case should look like that:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg3JK.png)

Could you help me?

Comment: Please don't use images, use formatted text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.*
from Tab1 a
left join Tab1 b
on a.OrderId = b.OrderId
and a.ProductId = b.ProductId
and b.status = 'packed'
and b.date <= a.date
where a.status = 'sent'
and b.OrderId is null
```

Comment: A good answer provides an explanation in addition to a working query